# Why is my inline asm not doing what I expect?

Tags: freepascal

I am knew to Pascal and can't understand what is going wrong in this assembly function:

```delphi
{$ASMMODE intel}
function SomeType.doSomething : boolean; assembler;
var i : integer; // for testing
asm
   mov EAX, field
   mov i, EAX // line 42
   and EAX, 4
   mov i, EAX
    //...
end;
```

Declaration of the class:

```
type
    SomeType = class(TObject)
    private
        field : integer;
        function doSomething : boolean;
    // ...
    end;
```

When `field` (a field of the class `SomeType`) is 4 before calling this method, the IDE (Lazarus) will report to me that `i` is assigned 8 in line 42 (see the line numbering above).

Is there something about the inline assembly that I am missing?

Why is the value of field not stored into and / or loaded from `EAX` correctly?

**Update**: I think I might be targeting 64 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read a field of an object isn't as simple an ordinary read from memory. Recall that member access implicitly goes through `Self`, so when you write `field` in your code, what you really mean is `Self.field`. To read the value from `Self.field`, the compiler would actually need to replace your code with something like this:

```
mov EAX, dword ptr [EAX + offset SomeType.field]
```

You can check the CPU view in the debugger to see whether that's what's really happening.

I think you'll find it's not. If Free Pascal interprets this code [the same way Delphi does](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Assembly_Expressions#Symbols), then a bare reference to `field` isn't including the implicit `Self` part. Instead, it's just the *offset* of that field in the class. Does `field` happen to be the second data member declared in your class (including anything declared in any ancestor classes)? If so, then that explains where you get 8 from. You'd get 0 for the VMT pointer, 4 for the first field, and so on, assuming you have nothing larger than four bytes, and everything gets aligned.

Change your code to read the value from memory, like in the line of code above. The type may or may not be allowed there; i.e. you might just write `offset field` instead of `offset SomeType.field`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your hints. I was getting an error `Asm: 16 or 32 bits references not supported.`, and a quick search told me it was because I am using 64 bits. When I change the code to use `rax` as indicated [here](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=11287.0), it instead gives other numbers (different ones on each run) and sometimes throws a segfault. What would be the correct code to use on a x64 architecture?

Comment: I can't write assembler code for a task I don't understand. Write your code in a high-level language, and if it's not good enough, work from there. (Let the compiler generate the assembly for you first. Then you can copy and modify it manually, knowing that you at least *started* with valid code.) However, I do know that the `Self` parameter isn't passed in the A register in 64-bit code. Refer to your documentation for 64-bit calling conventions.

Comment: You can write mov eax, [eax].SomeType.field to directly access a field.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I knew that applied for records, but wasn't sure about classes.